# How get data of heart rate of the RHYTMH+ Scoshe Bluetooth SMART device in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

Excuse me. Anyone know, How get the data of heart rate of the RHYTMH+ Scoshe Bluetooth SMART device (http://www.scosche.com/rhythm-plus) in real time? I want to process the data in an application in C# (Windows 8). I read that is possible via "Bluetooth Generic Attribute Profile - Heart Rate Service". Is true? And how do? ¿What requeriment are necessary in hardware and software?

Comment: any update? I need to get a heart rate (beat per minutue - only this number) and save it to SQL using c# .net but have no idea what kind of hardware can do this...

Comment: Hi. It depends on the connectivity of heart rate sensor, is BLE or previuos version?

Comment: did you finish this? what device do you use, can you recommend me?

Comment: Yes. I use the http://www.scosche.com/rhythm-plus . This device has BLE connectivity so you need your computer has an BLE adapter (I use this http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBBT400/). In software, you need Windows 8.1 that already brings BLE protocol stack (An example here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95)

Comment: Thanks so much for your info, I've never worked with any SDK before and there is not many people work with this kind of topic so it will be hard. Can you point out some main part of code such as:  get connection from device to pc, retrieve the data from devices ... Please post it as answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have the Rythm+ and get "instant heart rate" information on my android s4 using the App "Sensor BLE Connect".  It append each data record to a csv file on the root of my SD Card (here a few records)

```
Fri Jan 06 08:00:01 GMT+01:00 2017,59.  (Heart rate = 59)
Fri Jan 06 08:00:01 GMT+01:00 2017,59
Fri Jan 06 08:00:02 GMT+01:00 2017,58
Fri Jan 06 08:00:03 GMT+01:00 2017,57
```

I process it with a python script (I am a sporadic programmer)

NB Due to stability problem of the data capture process (linked to android? BT connectivity? ) I am interested in an alternative